# Select at least one checkbox AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS. I have a list of check box from which the latest one is compulsory. Initially all of them will be checked. Now I need that at least one should alway be checked.I don't want to fire a validation message but need that when the user tries to uncheck the last checked box then it will not be able to do so. I was trying to achieve in by using angularJS.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="search" class="lbl">
            <i class="fa fa-link"></i> Include:
        </label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="uploadCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.upload" tabindex="0">
                <label for="uploadCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="uploadCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="checkbox" id="editCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.edit" tabindex="0">
                <label for="editCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="editCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="downloadCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.download" tabindex="0">
                <label for="downloadCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="downloadCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Download
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="checkbox" id="userLogCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.userLog" tabindex="0">
                <label for="userLogCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="userLogCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;User Log
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="readMarksCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.readMarks" tabindex="0">
                <label for="readMarksCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="readMarksCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Read Marks
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="checkbox" id="userCreationCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.userCreationEdit" tabindex="0">
                <label for="userCreationCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="userCreationCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;User Creation/Edit Log
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="superCedeCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.superCede" tabindex="0">
                <label for="superCedeCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="superCedeCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Supercede
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to fire a validation message by using ng-required but I need to disable the last remaining checkbox. Has anyone any idea how can I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the **controller** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have developed a quick example, using the HTML you provide.

What you need to do, in order to incorporate it into your solution, is to include the two JS functions `checkForUncheckedBoxes` and `$scope.checkThemBoxes`, or rather their logic into the controller behind the checkboxes.

Another thing is to add `ng-change` attribute, which tells angular to run the `checkThemBoxes` function on every user change per checkbox. That function also takes the checkbox model attribute as a parameter and uses it for it's logic.

The logic of the functions is to check if the checkbox that is being checked is resulting in an uncheck and if so, checks if the other checkboxes are unchecked. If they are, the current checkbox takes a positive value, thus disallowing the user to uncheck it.

That is pretty much it. Thank you and have a nice day!

```js
angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      function checkForUncheckedBoxes(object, model) {
        for (var key in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && model != key) {
            if (object[key] == true)
              return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      $scope.checkThemBoxes = function(model) {
        if ($scope.auditLog.searchObj[model] == false && checkForUncheckedBoxes($scope.auditLog.searchObj, model))
          $scope.auditLog.searchObj[model] = true;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" ng-app="checkboxExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="search" class="lbl">
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i> Include:
    </label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('upload')" id="uploadCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.upload" tabindex="0">
        <label for="uploadCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="uploadCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('edit')" id="editCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.edit" tabindex="0">
        <label for="editCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="editCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('download')" id="downloadCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.download" tabindex="0">
        <label for="downloadCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="downloadCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Download
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('userLog')" id="userLogCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.userLog" tabindex="0">
        <label for="userLogCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="userLogCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;User Log
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('readMarks')" id="readMarksCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.readMarks" tabindex="0">
        <label for="readMarksCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="readMarksCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Read Marks
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 form-control-static">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('userCreationEdit')" id="userCreationCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.userCreationEdit" tabindex="0">
        <label for="userCreationCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="userCreationCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;User Creation/Edit Log
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkThemBoxes('superCede')" id="superCedeCB" ng-model="auditLog.searchObj.superCede" tabindex="0">
        <label for="superCedeCB" class="checkbox-white-label" id="superCedeCheckBox"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Supercede
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```